# Polyline buffer based on attribute value in ArcMap, choice in join/cap style?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, buffer

In QGIS I had no difficulty to create a buffer (in fact a single symbol) whose width is based on an attribute value of the polyline vector:

[image: Polyline buffer based on attribute value]

In ArcMap, I don't find any good solution. I tried:

- the buffer tool (in Analysis Tools/Proximity/Buffer), which doesn't
  let me choose the symbol and the side/end type,
- and the symbology > Multiple attributes > Symbol Size with the relevant attribute and "template" symbol, which doesn't apply the style chosen. The result is instead a green polyline whose width varies according to the attribute, but the style is not applied, as shown below (see the green line in the background, even if I had chosen a black/purple template):

[image]

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using? I have 10.2 and when I open the Buffer tool I have all of these options. I can select a field to use as the buffer width, which side(s) to buffer, and end type.

Comment: ArcMap 10.2 for Desktop Standard. Side type and end type are greyed.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked two questions or are confused with buffer terminology, so I've tried to answer both. Symbology is the depiction or representation of a layer or shape which can be largely for aesthetic purposes. eg.) a black line represents a road, a thick red line represents a highway, a thicker red line represents a highway with a speed limit > 100km.

A buffer creates a polygon based on an original feature and a given distance. eg) Within 5 km of a major road (line) would produce a polygon shape from a distance on each side from 5 km of the major road.

If you want to symbolize your line to have varying widths based on an attribute you can use Symbology--> Unique Values  and chose the field with the "width" value. Then you can right click on each symbol individually to change the line width, style or colour.

If you're wanting to buffer a line based on a buffer length value in your attribute table, you can also do this by ensuring that that field has valid units, see the example in [ArcGIS Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) eg.) if values were 10,20,30 and your map was projected in UTM then the buffer tool would interpret these values as meters.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. In fact the way (buffer or symbol) doesn't matter so much, my goal is to represent lines (road network) with width depending on feature attribute. In QGIS it's done very quickly (through symbol) and the aspect is nice but in ArcMap, no way. 
In ArcMap, using Symbology > Quantities > Proportional  symbols (which seems the most logic way...) I've bad looking result (see http://hpics.li/94985fb). No matter how I play with the miter/butt/round parameters for the symbol, I never manage to have a nice result as with QGIS (see my previous post).

Comment: Just to complete my comment above, for the same zone, see the difference with QGIS: http://hpics.li/18a61b7 : QGIS seems to present the data in a much more "smooth" way (parameters used in QGIS: single symbol, scale linear, size 1- to 10)